# How to force excel to gain focus and refresh the UI

Tags: excel

When I run a series of macros eventually excel loses focus and stops updating the screen this can occur looking at the screen or especially minimizing and doing something else on the computer. It can only be fixed by double clicking somewhere scrolling around maximizing and minimizing... but I can't seem to accomplish it in VBA I would hate to have to make an external macro to click into excel just to make the screen refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to see everything happen or do you want to just let it run and come back to it?  You can use the code `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to prevent the crazy jumping excel does and just come back as normal.

Comment: The problem is even after stopping all macros even without touching any Application settings Excel wants to lose focus and if you change tabs it will keep old information from other tabs and it will half update until you double click a couple times, it's clearly a nasty glitch in excel. For example I can look at the now() function and it will give mean old time, even while I have a loop running to force calculate... (auto calculation is on...) I know the now() function is updating but it won't visually display it because of how the UI decides to lock up from going away from excel for a while.